# Count occurrences of strings just once per row in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, row, countif

I have strings of spreadsheet data that need counting by 'type' but not instance.

```
   A   B C D
 1 Lin 1 2 1
 2 Tom 1 4 2
 3 Sue 3 1 4
```

The correct sum of students assigned to teacher 1 is 3, not 4. That teacher 1 meets Lin in lessons B and D is irrelevant to the count.

I borrowed a formula which works in Excel but not in Google Sheets where I and others need to keep and manipulate the data.

```
F5=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B$2:D$2, ROW($2:$4)-1, 0), E5)))

  A   B C D E 
2 Lin 1 2 1
3 Tom 1 4 2
4 Sue 3 1 4
5           1 [exact string being searched for, ie a teacher name]
```

I don't know what is not being understood by Google Sheets in that formula. Does anyone know the correct expression to use, or a more efficient way to get the accurate count I need, without duplicates within rows inflating the count?

Comment: Please describe what the rows and columns signify in the example you provided.

Comment: Each row is a record of teaching support to one student. Each column B, C and D may or may not contain a string which is a teacher's name. Cell B1 and D1 both contain a teacher's name such as Smith. Lin is supported by Smith in two different lessons but I need to count that Smith supports Lin, Tom and Sue = 3 students.

Comment: I would `CONCATENATE` the rows and use `FIND` and `IF` and `ISERROR`, to get `0`or`1` for each row - like `=IF(ISERROR(FIND($A$1,CONCAT(A3:D3))),0,1)` - and then probably make that an array formula.

Comment: That sumproduct is wrong. The offset should be using ROW($1:$3)-1 or ROW($2:$4)-2, not ROW($2:$4)-1.

Comment: ashleedawg I follow the logic of marking a row to true or false for the presence of a teacher name. However, in the formula you suggest, I am not sure where or how I tell the spreadsheet to look for a specific teacher name.

Comment: I don't think offset will work in the way you want in Google Sheets. Mmult should work in both, or there could be a specific google sheets way probably using split/join/transpose - not of them as straightforward as you'd wish unfortunately.

Comment: Tom Sharpe, thanks for the advice. I didn't know what was being misunderstood in Google Sheets and this is something to investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the mmult way, which works by finding the row totals of students assigned to teacher 1 etc., then seeing how many of the totals are greater than 0.

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(--(mmult(n(B2:D4=E5),transpose(column(B2:D4)))>0)))
```

or

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(sign(mmult(n(B2:D4=E5),transpose(column(B2:D4))))))
```

Also works in Excel if entered as an array formula without the ArrayFormula wrapper.

A specific Google Sheets one can be quite short

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTUNIQUE((B2:D4=E5)*row(B2:D4)))-1
```

counting the unique rows containing a match.

*Note* - I am subtracting 1 in the last formula above because I am assuming there is at least one zero (non-match) which should be ignored. This would fail in the extreme case where all students in all classes are assigned to the same teacher so you have a matrix (e.g.) of all 1's. This would be more theoretically correct:

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTUNIQUE(if(B2:D4=E5,row(B2:D4),"")))
```

Comment: I see the reference to the cell E5 where I have written the string I am searching for (a teacher's name). I will try this.